# Is there a clear distinction between the various intra- and intermolecular interactions?

Tags: bond, intermolecular-forces

Wikipedia lists dipole-dipole, hydrogen bonding and Van der Waals under [intermolecular interactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermolecular_force), and hydrophobic, ionic and covalent under [intramolecular interactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intramolecular_force).

1. Is there a clear distinction between each and every one of these interactions? For example: isn't hydrogen bond a private case of VdW? aren't ionic bonds and hydrophobic interactions private cases of dipole-dipole interaction?
2. Is there one single chart that differentiates all of these types of interaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, there aren't clear distinctions, particularly between intramolecular and intermolecular interactions.**

First, a caveat that we generally divide molecules along covalent bonds. So those are strictly intramolecular, in my opinion. (Network solids are a bit tricky to classify.)

Let's go through the rest one at a time.

1. **Dipole-dipole**: These are usually *intermolecular*, but certainly in larger, more flexible molecules, *intramolecular* polar-polar interactions can change the molecular shape and preferred conformation. (Think about tying together two bar magnets on one piece of string. Certainly they'll interact.)
2. **Hydrogen bonds**: Yes, many of these are *intermolecular*. However, there **definitely** are *intramolecular* hydrogen bonds:

[image]

3. **Van der Waals**: Again, these can be *intermolecular*. In even a moderate molecule, *intramolecular* non-bonded van der Waals interactions can change conformations and geometries. Consider axial/equitorial preferences in cyclohexanes or other types of ["steric clashes"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steric_effects) because of big bulky groups. These are the effects of van der Waals interactions.

**OK, so all the intermolecular interactions are also intramolecular ones too.**

4. **Hydrophobic interactions**: I usually think of these as *[intermolecular](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Physical_Chemistry/Physical_Properties_of_Matter/Atomic_and_Molecular_Properties/Intermolecular_Forces/Hydrophobic_interactions)* but similar considerations make sense as intramolecular for the reasons I outline under van der Waals interactions above.
5. **Ionic**: I'll just think of these as different partial charges in a molecule. Clearly electrostatic interactions occur both inside a molecule (e.g., electrostatic non-bonded interactions changing conformations and geometries) and as *intermolecular* forces, e.g., water-cation interactions.

**So besides covalent interactions, which we use to divide "inside" and "outside" a molecule, all of these are both intermolecular and intramolecular interactions.**

I'm not sure I've seen a great chart. Maybe someone else can comment.

Comment: I've read that it's not vdW repulsion in ethane that causes the molecule to favor a staggered conformation but rather hyperconjugation ...your thoughts?

Comment: http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v411/n6837/full/411565a0.html

Comment: Definitely hyperconjugation and other effects can cause conformational preferences. But there are definitely longer range VdW steric effects, eg substitutions around the inter-ring bond in biphenyls.

Comment: I came across [this chart](http://faculty.sdmiramar.edu/fgarces/zCourse/All_Year/Ch100_OL/aMy_FileLec/04OL_LecNotes_Ch100/05_CompoundBonding/505_IMF_Water/505_pic/descriptionIMF.gif), which seems to differentiate firstly by "basis of attraction" and secondly by bond energy, and it seems that anything above 600kJ/mol is intramolecular, and anything below 75kJ/mol is intermolecular. What do you think?

Comment: While these trends may be *largely* true, for the reasons I give above, all the interactions can be both intermolecular and intramolecular.

Comment: so one final question (rephrasing #1 in the original question above): how do I know to name a given interaction, if for example it can be at the same time ionic, hydrophobic and dipole-dipole?

Comment: Well, those three are quite different. Hydrophobic interactions are generally non-charged components. Ionic are fully charged. Dipole are polar (e.g., not charged, but clear partial charges, e.g C-F). So for that, you just look at the molecules themselves.